# Excel formula for average excluding x highest values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for the average over a column, whereby x lines are excluded. The data is not sorted. The data to be excluded should be the x bottom lines if the column was sorted from lowest to highest.

example 
data (column) {2;2;3;1;2}

cut-off "x" = 2

sorted {1;2;2;2;3}

cut off last 2 lines {1;2;2}

average = 1.66

Comment: Are you ok with a helper column? Is your column data always starting in row 1 or it can start in any row?

Comment: There should not not be a helper column. At least not in a sense that it is visible to the user and adds extra steps the user needs to do.

Comment: for all intents and purposes it always starts at cell A1 and ends at A5

Comment: Can your cut off ever be same as total number of rows, it won't be meaningful though?  Are you going to put the cutoff number in same cell?

Comment: I need not take into consideration 'weird' situations where the cut-off is equal or higher than the number of rows
Yes,the cut-off aka "x" will be a number taken from a cell, say B1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution proposed uses a Helper Column but that can be hidden always and won't require any user intervention.

Your data is in Cells A1:A5

In B1 (Helper Column) Put this formula and drag it down till B5, You now have B1 thru B5 as sorted list of A1:A5. Now simply Hide Column B.

```
=SMALL($A$1:$A$5,ROW(1:1))
```

In Cell C1 user should put the value of cut off number.

In D1 put the following formula

```
=IF(OR(C1>=ROW(B5),C1=0),"Invalid CutOff",AVERAGE(INDEX(B1:B5,1):INDEX(INDEX(B1:B5,1):B5,MAX(ROW(B1:B5))-C1)))
```

and from within the Formula Bar press CTRL + SHIFT  + ENTER to make it an array formula.

[image]

Comment: with helper table this works nicely. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula if you want to remove just 2 (largest number)

`=(SUM(A1:A5)-LARGE(A1:A5,1)-LARGE(A1:A5,2))/(COUNT(A1:A5)-2)`

your numbers are in A1:A5
Large(A1:A5,1) is the maximum
Large(A1:A5,2) is the second largest number
and so on if you want more
than you divide the sum by the count of numbers minus (-) the count of largest you want to cutoff

Comment: It needs to be dynamic. The formula looks up a cell value, and it that value is 15, the formula will remove 15 rows.